# Recognizing years without preposition with Duckling

Tags: named-entity-recognition, duckling

I'm trying to get the year from this sentence :

`"events 2015"`

Only grabs 2015 as a number.

But if I put the sentence in https://duckling.wit.ai/ grabs 2015 correctly as year, even if I just put 2015.

What can I do to have this behav in my side?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to add locale in your request.
It works with "en_us" or "en_gb"